# Rolling shop-bought pastry without flour

Tags: flour, pastry

Last night I got a block of frozen shortcrust pastry out of the freezer as I'm planning on making a pie tonight.

It has just occurred to me that to roll it out, I'll need flour, and I don't have any!

Is there any way that I can roll pastry out without using flour? Or is my only option to go to the supermarket on the way home and buy some?